# Android emulation under KVM on Ubuntu - Rotation 90

Tags: android, ubuntu, rotation, virtual-machine, kvm

I got Android running, with google app store, under KVM on Ubuntu, installing from android-x86-4.0-r1-thinkpad.iso

When i run certain games, they rotate the android screen 90degrees, the mouse movement rotates with the screen (e.g. UP now moves left)

Is there a way to rotate the KVM vnc screen that is displayed back 90deg to make the application usable ?

Comment: I assume turning your head 90 degrees as a non-technical solution is out of the question :)

Comment: @Chris it is close to the solution I’m looking at, a external monitor that can physically rotate.

Comment: Yikes. I was joking. I hope you're able to find a good software based solution to this...